# Pulling data from mysql based on Array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a file `file.php` and inside my file I am using the code bellow to pull some data from my database and display some information.

My code is

```
$array = $_GET['theurl']; // My url looks like myfile.php?theurl=1,2,3 (id,s)
$sqlnt4 = "select * from mytable WHERE `id` IN ($array)";
$rsdt4 = mysql_query($sql);
$tc4a = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsdt4);
$mycomma4 = ",";
if ($tc4a['a_youtube'] == "#"){
}else{
    while ($tc4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsdt4))
    {
        echo $tc4['a_youtube'];
        echo ",";
    }
}
```

I expect to echo the infos of the two `id's` (in array) inside my while function, but it returns the results only from the first.

Any ideas?

Comment: Idea1: Stop using mysql_* and use Pdo instead.

Comment: you have 2 rows in result, you fetch once outside while-loop with no output, then once inside with one output - so you'll have only 1 row in your output

Comment: And this is why you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: The OP's been told countless times about the use of `mysql_*` functions. I'm starting to think she's grown a particular fondness of working with "old code". @Goikiu Hey, maybe she likes the attention?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am confusing on `$sql` :

```
$sqlnt4 = "select * from mytable WHERE `id` IN ($array)";
$rsdt4 = mysql_query($sql);
```

Can you take a look after changing below:

```
$sqlnt4 = "select * from mytable WHERE `id` IN ($array)";
$rsdt4 = mysql_query($sqlnt4);
```

Comment: Sorry for this was a mistyped.. my code is like this that you provide me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

First that's extremely vulnerable to security issues - I hope this isn't used in production and just for playing around.

I recommend switching to PDO, or at the very least securing your variables.

To put that array into the query, you need to implode it into a list, as such.

```
$list = implode(',', $array);
```

You can then use the list in the statement, which will look like `1,2,3`.

**Edit:**

I've just realized your $array value isn't actually an array - have you missed code out or is it badly named?

Comment: It's for my personal use.. $list is has already look like this myfile.php?theurl=1,2,3,4

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_assoc: "Returns an associative array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead." http://pt2.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc

Try mysql_fetch_rows to return all matching rows into an array.